# Android OpenGL Performance Drop

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am experimenting with the Camera to MP4 example here:
https://bigflake.com/mediacodec/CameraToMpegTest.java.txt

My test app uses roughly the same code, and when I record at 1280x720 then everything is fine.
But for some reason switching to use 1920x1080 then the FPS drops and CPU usage increases.

Profiling CPU usage the problem seems to be the `GLES20.glDrawArrays` call.
It goes from using about 2% of CPU cycles to almost 40%. The only thing that's different is the camera preview resolution.

It seems to be crossing some sort of cache or memory re-allocation boundary. I don't have much OpenGL experience, and am not sure how I could debug this. Any advice on what I could look for?

EDIT:
Enabling Androids GPU usage overlay indicates no noticeable difference.
[image]
[image]

Comment: I suspect that `GLES20.glDrawArrays` is a red herring. By increasing the resolution, you're increasing the load on the GPU. When your frame is GPU bound, the CPU is going to have to wait somewhere eventually and often that's on the first draw call of a frame (or often glClear). There isn't a massive amount of scope to optimize the GPU time AFAICT so I suspect you've just hit the performance limit of your device. Do you have a way to profile the GPU (it can be difficult on Android)?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I think you're probably right, though showing GPU usage on-screen doesn't indicate as much (screenshots added to main post). I had commented out the glClears, enabling those puts them right up there with CPU cycle usage.

Comment: By increasing the resolution (in this case, you are rendering 45% more pixels), you are increasing the load for fragment shader. This will increase the GPU response time for each draw. Thus increasing the overall CPU wait time. To prove my hypothesis, you can optimise the fragment shader to see if your CPU usage decreases.

Comment: I think that GPU profiler you've enabled only indicates GPU workload from the Android UI system. I don't think it measures workload from your app's own OpenGL calls.